# Rails generate devise install problem (LoadError files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

When i run this command in cmd - rails generate devise:install

i got this issue

```
C:\Users\Andrew\instagram-clone>rails generate devise:install
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext (LoadError)
Did you mean?  3.0.0/devkit
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Andrew/instagram-clone/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)
C:\Users\Andrew\instagram-clone>rails generate devise:install
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext (LoadError)
Did you mean?  3.0.0/devkit
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.17/lib/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Andrew/instagram-clone/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)
```

Maybe smb has same error?
Will be very grateful for answer Thx

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but from the trace I'd search for solutions to "cannot load such file -- pg_ext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the stack trace tells that you do not have the PostgreSQL libraries installed on the target machine. So, to resolve that issue, is that you can download the stable version of the software [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows) and make sure that you have the development libraries checked in the setup process. This will require you to close and reopen all of your active cmd sessions after install.

After that, re-run the `bundle install --force` (if you are using bundler older than 2.1) or `bundle install --redownload` (if you are on Bundler 2.1 or later) on the Rails project and should be able to compile and function correctly.

If it is installed and doesn't work with the above options, re-install the gem by doing `gem install pg -f` or use a pre-release version (on a development machine) by `gem install pg --pre` to see whether they may or may not resolve your problem.